# Roambi - Framework

Tags: iphone

I saw the Roambi visulaizer. It looks pretty good. I am using the coreplot for develop the graph based app. Could any one know which framework is used to develop the roambi?

Answer (score 0):

I think they would have used core-plot framework. http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/